# Statistic model beyond ANOVA using SPSS

Tags: spss, anova, mixed-models

I have two groups in which I compare two times (before and after treatment).

At first, I tried an repeated measures ANOVA and observed significant difference between groups. However, I have the following question: baseline means (time 1) are very different between groups and we fear that the significant result of ANOVA is due to this difference between baselines.

Therefore, we consider using another statistical model, specifically mixed models. However, the SPSS does not run telling me that "no valid case was found".

I talked to a statistician who said the problem is that the number of observations (rows) is less than the number of columns (dependent variables).

Would anyone know if this information makes sense? And does anyone know of any statistical model that would help us control this difference between baselines using SPSS?

Comment: Please consider add a code sample of your specific problem so people can help you better

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that this question is off topic here. We're glad to help in any SPSS programming questions, but for statistics you should post in [stats.stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) Good luck!